# What's the difference between a rake task and a worker class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I hope my question make sense, I'm not a rails guy and I started looking to an existing project to learn.

This project sends emails in background on certain events using "workers". There is one email in particular that is sent using a rake task. From what I can tell, there is no difference to emails sent on workers and it seems to me it could have been a worker too.

What's the difference of using a custom rake task over a worker? What you can do with a rake task that a worker can't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rake tasks are usually entered by you on the command line.
Worker jobs are usually initiated by the running application. The background worker then takes the job at appropriate moment and runs it.

Depending on the task you have it's possible to use both, the difference is probably who is supposed to do it. It's not a very good idea to run rake from the app but it's possible (via shell command).

Comment: Isn't possible to schedule a rake task and then would be equivalent to the worker job?

Comment: Yes, you could schedule a shell command that would run a rake task, but that's not a really good idea. It's hard to debug, you may have problems executing the task because ruby or rake is not found in path, permission troubles, how to handle errors, etc. On top of it all it's really a double work because the same work could be extracted into some kind of third class and both rake and worker would only call that.